# Cross-compilation with Clang can't find C++ headers, GCC can

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, clang, cross-compiling

I'm trying to build my application for two different single board computers. One uses GCC as cross-compiler and I could not find a prebuilt GCC cross-compiler for another one so I decided to give Clang a go. Currently I'm stuck at the point where Clang can't find standard C++ headers like `<algorithm>`.

On another hand, GCC cross-compiler builds my application successfully. The source code and all `CMakeLists.txt` files are the same between these two build attempts. The only difference is the toolchain file. They use different sysroot paths.

I checked that `algorithm` file is at `C:/Bananapi_rootfs/usr/include/c++/8/` directory, but Clang doesn't include it in the search list for include files.

Do I have to add that directory to my toolchain file manually or there is a magic switch I'm lacking which would make Clang find that directory on its own?

The Clang command output is:

```
[build]  "C:/msys64/clang64/bin/clang++.exe" -cc1 -triple aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu -emit-obj -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name format.cc -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -pic-is-pie -mframe-pointer=non-leaf -fmath-errno -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -funwind-tables=2 -target-cpu generic -target-feature +neon -target-feature +v8a -target-abi aapcs -tune-cpu cortex-a55 -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=C:/Users/AZARUB~1/DOCUME~1/my_app/build/fmt -resource-dir C:/msys64/clang64/lib/clang/17 -dependency-file "CMakeFiles\\fmt.dir\\src\\format.cc.o.d" -MT fmt/CMakeFiles/fmt.dir/src/format.cc.o -sys-header-deps -I "C:\\Users\\AZARUB~1\\DOCUME~1\\my_app\\fmt\\include" -D NDEBUG -isysroot C:/Bananapi_rootfs -internal-isystem C:/msys64/clang64/lib/clang/17/include -internal-isystem C:/Bananapi_rootfs/usr/local/include -internal-isystem C:/Bananapi_rootfs/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/include -internal-externc-isystem C:/Bananapi_rootfs/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem C:/Bananapi_rootfs/include -internal-externc-isystem C:/Bananapi_rootfs/usr/include -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=gnu++17 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=C:/Users/AZARUB~1/DOCUME~1/my_app/build/fmt -ferror-limit 19 -fno-signed-char -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -vectorize-loops -vectorize-slp -target-feature -fmv -faddrsig -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o "CMakeFiles\\fmt.dir\\src\\format.cc.o" -x c++ "C:\\Users\\azarubkin\\Documents\\my_app\\fmt\\src\\format.cc"
[build] clang -cc1 version 17.0.6 based upon LLVM 17.0.6 default target x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
[build] ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Bananapi_rootfs/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/include"
[build] ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Bananapi_rootfs/include"
[build] #include "..." search starts here:
[build] #include <...> search starts here:
[build]  C:\Users\AZARUB~1\DOCUME~1\my_app\fmt\include
[build]  C:/msys64/clang64/lib/clang/17/include
[build]  C:/Bananapi_rootfs/usr/local/include
[build]  C:/Bananapi_rootfs/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu
[build]  C:/Bananapi_rootfs/usr/include
[build] End of search list.
```

The GCC command itself is:

```
"C:\\SysGCC\\beaglebone\\bin\\arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.exe --sysroot=C:/beaglebone_rootfs  -IC:\\Users\\AZARUB~1\\DOCUME~1\\my_app\\fmt\\include -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -Wp,-v  -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -o CMakeFiles\\fmt.dir\\src\\os.cc.o -c \"C:\\Users\\azarubkin\\Documents\\my_app\\fmt\\src\\os.cc\"
```

The GCC command output is:

```
[build] [ 10%] Building CXX object fmt/CMakeFiles/fmt.dir/src/os.cc.o
[build] ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\sysgcc\beaglebone\include\arm-linux-gnueabihf\c++\8"
[build] ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\sysgcc\beaglebone\arm-linux-gnueabihf\include\arm-linux-gnueabihf\c++\8\arm-linux-gnueabihf"
[build] ignoring duplicate directory "c:\sysgcc\beaglebone\arm-linux-gnueabihf\include\c++\8"
[build] ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\sysgcc\beaglebone\include\arm-linux-gnueabihf\c++\8"
[build] ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\sysgcc\beaglebone\arm-linux-gnueabihf\include\arm-linux-gnueabihf\c++\8"
[build] ignoring duplicate directory "c:\sysgcc\beaglebone\arm-linux-gnueabihf\include\c++\8\backward"
[build] ignoring duplicate directory "c:\sysgcc\beaglebone\lib\gcc\arm-linux-gnueabihf\8\include"
[build] ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\beaglebone_rootfs\mnt\f\gnu\beaglebone\out\include\arm-linux-gnueabihf"
[build] ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\beaglebone_rootfs\mnt\f\gnu\beaglebone\out\include"
[build] ignoring duplicate directory "c:\sysgcc\beaglebone\lib\gcc\arm-linux-gnueabihf\8\include-fixed"
[build] ignoring duplicate directory "c:\sysgcc\beaglebone\arm-linux-gnueabihf\include"
[build] #include "..." search starts here:
[build] #include <...> search starts here:
[build]  C:\Users\AZARUB~1\DOCUME~1\my_app\fmt\include
[build]  c:\sysgcc\beaglebone\arm-linux-gnueabihf\include\c++\8
[build]  c:\sysgcc\beaglebone\arm-linux-gnueabihf\include\c++\8\backward
[build]  c:\sysgcc\beaglebone\lib\gcc\arm-linux-gnueabihf\8\include
[build]  c:\sysgcc\beaglebone\lib\gcc\arm-linux-gnueabihf\8\include-fixed
[build]  c:\sysgcc\beaglebone\arm-linux-gnueabihf\include
[build]  c:\beaglebone_rootfs\usr\include\arm-linux-gnueabihf
[build]  c:\beaglebone_rootfs\usr\include
[build] End of search list.
```

Comment: `--sysroot C:/Bananapi_rootfs` should be enough I think? Can you show your cmake toolchain file? I think cmake has a variable for sysroot.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat here you go: https://pastebin.com/dLrFb2mq

Comment: Hmm. Can you try building a single manually, without CMake? Just `--sysroot=C:/Bananapi_rootfs --rtlib=libgcc --unwindlib=libgcc --target=aarch64-linux-gnu -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a55`. I'd also try running CMake build in verbose move to see the flags it passes to Clang (`-v` reports something else).

Comment: `$ clang++ --sysroot=C:/Bananapi_rootfs --rtlib=libgcc --unwindlib=libgcc --target=aarch64-linux-gnu -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a55 -stdlib=libstdc++ -Ifmt/include fmt/src/format.cc` gives 
`In file included from fmt/src/format.cc:8:
fmt/include/fmt/format-inl.h:11:10: fatal error: 'algorithm' file not found.`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat but if I don't switch the standard C++ library, I get: `$ clang++ --sysroot=C:/Bananapi_rootfs --rtlib=libgcc --unwindlib=libgcc --target=aarch64-linux-gnu -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a55 -Ifmt/include fmt/src/format.cc` which gives `ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lc++
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`. Does it see the include file in that case?

Comment: Can you try the first command again with `-v`, please? Does it show the same include dir list as in your question?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes it does.

Comment: I see... Can you share a download link for the SDK?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat as for the Clang compiler, I installed it as a part of MSYS2 in CLANG64 environment. The sysroot was downloaded from the live board manually with rsync. Do you want me to upload it somewhere (the C:/Bananapi_rootfs directory)?

Comment: Yep, upload the sysroot somewhere please. I'll try it on my machine.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f9e991OgauBzE4jxHLbUQCvmKyMVC__k/
The size is ~250 Mb. You'll need 7-zip archiver (https://www.7-zip.org/) to unpack.

Comment: Can you please link to the original image file you have installed on the board? Perhaps you didn't copy enough stuff into the sysroot (like `/include`).

Comment: I got it to build, but it feels hacky. I added `/usr` to the end of `--sysroot`, and created a symlink named `usr` inside the existing `usr` directory, pointing to `.` (`cd root/usr`, `ln -s . usr` on Linux, unsure how you'd do it on Windows). I hope that if you copy more stuff to the sysroot, the symlink will be unnecessary.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat please see https://wiki.banana-pi.org/Banana_Pi_BPI-M5#Linux - I used https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Y-GuZYovWRgBvt0z7FLnIuBJufVFflvv?usp=sharing link from that page which corresponds to 2023-08-30-debian-10-buster-bpi-m5-m2pro-aarch64-sd-emmc.img image.

I also managed to build my app (without extra symlink) but I had to specify additional include dirs (`include_directories(SYSTEM "${SYSROOT_PATH}/usr/include/c++/8" "${SYSROOT_PATH}/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/c++/8")`. I was wondering if it is really necessary.

Please see the original image link in this comment.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat your approach worked for me as well (adding extra symlink inside `/usr` to itself). I wonder what makes Clang recognize those additional c++ include dirs with it (and prevents without).

Comment: I think that if you also copy `/include` to the sysroot, then `--sysroot` will understand `C:/Bananapi_rootfs` directly without `/usr` and without the symlink. (I hoped I'd be able to get easily get the sysroot from the image, but nope.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat there is no `/include` directory on the live board. You can open that image file with 7-zip archiver as well. It has some nesting levels, but you'll eventually get to the root partition contents.